# issues trying to monitor log file with powershell

Tags: powershell, logging, monitoring

I want to monitor a log file which is constantly being added to (every few seconds) over the course of a 2 hour period. I am currently using Get-Content file.txt –Wait which displays the content to the screen and allows me to see what’s being added to the file but I need to take this a step further and actually watch for specific messages and if something I’m looking for in the log file appears, then do something. Initially I used a .net file reader with a for loop as shown below

```
try {
for(;;) {
    $line = $log_reader.ReadLine()
    if ($line -match "something")
    { 
    Write-Host "we have a match"
    Break
    }
```

The issue with this however is that it was causing the process that is generating the log file to fall over - it throws an error (because another process is using the log file it’s creating – I thought this was odd because I assumed the .net stream reader would just be ‘reading’ the file). I don’t have any control over the process which is generating the log file so I don’t know what it’s doing exactly (I’m guessing it has the file in read/write mode with some kind of lock which gets upset when I try to read the file using a .net stream reader). Doing a Get-Content on the file doesn’t seem to cause this issue however.
The question is, how can I use something like Get-Content (or another process) to monitor the log file but move onto another part of the script if a message I’m looking for in the log appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you constantly want to monitor the log file and catch the desired pattern as soon as it appears:

```
while(!(Select-String -path 'c:\log.txt' -pattern 'something' -quiet)){};
## when finds the pattern, comes out of the loop and proceed to next part of the script
Write-host 'we have a match'
```

You may want to change the path of the file to yours.

Though this would work, there will be a lot of processing that your computer have to do, since the while loop is a constant loop. If you can afford to introduce some delay, like if it is OK to find the error 30 sec or whatever is your threshold, after it appeared, then you can consider introducing sleep:

```
while(!(Select-String -path 'c:\log.txt' -pattern 'something' -quiet)){start-sleep -seconds 30};
## when finds the pattern, comes out of the loop and proceed to next part of the script
Write-host 'we have a match'
```

You can write a small logic to terminate the script after two hours, otherwise it would become an infinite loop, if 'something' doesn't gets written at all in the log file.

Edit 1:

If you want to print the new lines at the console, you can try manipulating a bit like:

```
    while(!(Select-String -path 'c:\log.txt' -pattern 'something' -quiet))
     { 
      $a = get-content 'c:\log.txt'
      if(($a.count) -gt $b )
       {
        $a[$b..($a.count)]
       }

      $b = ($a.count) 
      start-sleep -Seconds 30
     }

   ## To print the line containing the pattern when while loop exited 
  (Get-content 'c:\log.txt')[-1]
```

Comment: will this method allow multiple patterns/conditions and if I implemented the above solution how would I also get it to output the contents of the log file to the console (like Get-Content would)?

Comment: Yes it can. You can even use regular exprssions for pattern. Type 'help select-string -full' to know more. But it would exit as long as it finds any one of the patterns. You can write get-content 'c:\log.txt' in place of write-host above to display entire content of the file.

Comment: Cheers, but what I need is the output of the log file to be constantly outputted to the console windows as well (i.e what get-content file.txt -wait) does?

Comment: I've not worked with -wait before, but i think same can be achieved with a bit manipulation. I have edited my code. Please let me know if it helps. Although, there should be more elegant solutions out there for Powershell V2.

Comment: it was helpful thanks for this! I also kind of got what I was looking for with the following:

while(!(Select-String -path $upgradelog -pattern 'some error' -quiet)){ Get-Content $upgradelog };

Only thing I need to add is defining multiple patterns to look for...

Comment: just to clarify - in the latest bit of code you created there, are you creating an array and adding to it? what's the -gt for?

Comment: By using only {Get-Content $upgradelog} in while loop, you are printing entire log everytime the Where loop executes.So, to simulate -wait behaviour(i.e, to show new lines that got added),i added a small logic. It reads the file in every while loop($a), compares number of lines from previous time($b), if the count has increased(-gt is greater than), then print the new lines. $a and $b both gets overwritten every time while loop executes. I'm not building $a array explicitly, when you use get-content, powershell builds it for you. You can verify that using $a.gettype().